# How to Expand IIS Express Cache Size with ASP.NET 4.5.2

Tags: asp.net, asp-net-mvc-1

I am currently using the static cache built into ASP.NET quite a bit and I'm finding that my IIS server cache's a lot more than my Visual Studio IIS Express when I'm doing development.  It's causing me a problem because it's hard to simulate m production because IIS Express stops taking new cached objects.

I looked in the IIS Express configuration file but can't find any settings to increase cache size.

How can I increase the amount of cache available in my IIS Express ASP.NET App?

Comment: did you try what switch IIS Express to x64?

Comment: changing to x64 did not help